# CIAO 4.11 on Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 - Installed correctly but "command not found" for any CIAO command

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-18.04

I've been trying for a long time to make a data analysis program CIAO ( http://cxc.harvard.edu/ciao/index.html) work on Ubuntu 18.04 on my computer that runs under Windows 10.

I've managed to install it and run the smoke tests successfully, I've installed ds9 and Xming in order to open linux windows in my windows environment.

One week ago I tried to use it for the first time and I could use the different CIAO command like download_chandra_obsid 1783 or open a .fits document on ds9 within the terminal (I can still do that, but not within the terminal). I even downloaded one set of data (1730) which I tried to access, but did not succeed.

Here is my terminal:

```
james@MSI:~$ export DISPLAY=:0
james@MSI:~$ ./ds9 &
[1] 16
james@MSI:~$ bash /home/james/ciao-4.11/bin/ciao.bash
CIAO configuration is complete...
CIAO 4.11 Wednesday, December  5, 2018
  bindir      : /home/james/ciao-4.11/bin
  CALDB       : 4.8.2
james@MSI:~$ download_chandra_obsid 1843
download_chandra_obsid: command not found
james@MSI:~$ cd 1730/
james@MSI:~/1730$ cd primary/
james@MSI:~/1730/primary$ ls
acisf01730N004_cntr_img2.fits.gz  acisf01730N004_full_img2.fits.gz  acisf01730_000N004_fov1.fits.gz
acisf01730N004_cntr_img2.jpg      acisf01730N004_full_img2.jpg      orbitf079704300N001_eph1.fits.gz
acisf01730N004_evt2.fits.gz       acisf01730_000N004_bpix1.fits.gz  pcadf079779156N004_asol1.fits.gz
james@MSI:~/1730/primary$ punlearn fluximage
punlearn: command not found
james@MSI:~/1730/primary$ fluximage acisf01730N004_evt2.fits.gz
fluximage: command not found
```

The last lines, I tried to follow this thread to see if I could do anything to my set of data: http://cxc.harvard.edu/ciao/threads/fluxes/

It's my first time asking my question here, please feel free to ask me for more information and thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it was quick, my professor took the time to help me and run the following command:

```
james@MSI:~$ source /home/james/ciao-4.11/bin/ciao.bash -o
CIAO configuration is complete...
CIAO 4.11 Wednesday, December  5, 2018
  bindir      : /home/james/ciao-4.11/bin
  CALDB       : 4.8.2
´´´

From there, everything seemed to work.
```